# tinymce-4 with custom buttons working fine in Chrome & Firefox But not working in Safari - Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, tinymce-4

OK.. Currently i am working to make an `custom editor` using `tinymce`. I have used few button control method to execute the these control from outsite the `tinymce toolbar`. and possibly i did that and it is working fine in Chrome and Firefox.

But when i turned my head towards `Safari` ... i found myself exhausted because what i have done.. is a 2 days work and i cannot believe that it is not working in Safari.

I am using latest version of TinyMce with inline editor.

[PLEASE CHECK THIS FIDDLE](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ngdaab/494)

**[UPDATED]**

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .buttons { float:left;margin:10px;border:1px solid black;padding:4px 7px; }
</style>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(e) {
        function customfunction() {
                    e.focus(true);
                    alert('Hello TinyMce');
            }


    e.addButton('testButton', {
        id: "testButton",
        text: 'Example',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
                customfunction();
            }
        });
}
);
tinymce.init({
        selector: "#textareasDiv",
        inline: true,
        plugins: "example",
        toolbar: "testButton",
        menubar: false,
        fixed_toolbar_container: "#toolbarCon",     
        inline_styles : true,

    });

function customfunction()
{

    document.getElementById("testButton").click();
}

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="textareasDiv" style="width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">Please select the text and click any of these buttons.</div>
<div id="toolbarCon" style="display:none;"></div>

<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('Bold');return false;"><div class="bold buttons">B</div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('Italic');return false;"><div class="italic buttons"><em>I</em></div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('Underline');return false;"><div class="underline buttons">U</div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('FontName',false,'Andale Mono');return false;"><div class="jLeft buttons" >Andale Mono</div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('FontName',false,'Courier New');return false;"><div class="jCenter buttons" >Courier New</div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('FontName',false,'Tahoma');return false;"><div class="jRight buttons" >Tahoma</div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('FontName',false,'Impact');return false;"><div class="jRight buttons" >Impact</div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="customfunction();return false;"><div class="jRight buttons" >Custom Button</div></a>
```

There are some issues coming when i run this fiddle on `Safari` as well as my own file.

1. When i selected some text in textarea and clicked on Any Buttons, it appears style on whole line along with my selected text. Style should be appeared only my selected Text?
2. It should be able to toggle style like i clicked on Bold button it appears style but when i again clicked on the same Bold button it should be normal. Nothing happening?
3. I also added a custom plugin for some other task and when clicked on the custom buttom nothing happens. and in other browser it gives me alert message.

One thing i have also checked `tinymce demo page` [HERE](http://www.tinymce.com/index.php)  but once i checked this demo in Safari same condition there, no toggle happens after clicking on `Bold,Italic,Underline`.

But its all working in `Chrome and FireFox`. SO whats wrong with `Safari`. Is that not supported by `TinyMce`? OR Some other thing is happening?

Comment: everything works on safari 7, same on safari 5, except custom function  can not find document.getElementById("testButton"), looks like tinymce do not support old safari well?

Comment: Is that really possible?? 5 and 7 are working and 6 is not? BTW thanks for you reply.

Comment: try on safari web inspector with  document.getElementById("testButton").click(); or other selector to be sure

Comment: Do you really want to spend much time on supporting _old_ safari? Market share is less than 1%

Comment: NO i really dont want that but what about those users who are still using old versions of safari?? Market share surely will go up if this work..

Comment: Safari not supporting getelbyid that good -> use something like $("#bla").trigger("blubb"); then.

This should work I guess,

Comment: @FelixLahmer - You should read my issue points 1 and 2 once again. Hope you will help me for these points. BTW i will try using `$("#bla").trigger("blubb");`.

Comment: @ShailParas I´d love to help you with them, but I cant..... thats why I added a comment

Comment: @FelixLahmer - No Problem.. but dont you think this could be the problem with tinymce? because i also have tried tinymce demo. it is also not working for me.. Same issue as i have mention in Point 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check i done small changes this http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ngdaab/535

```
 $("#testButton2").children("button").click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its working now, but there are two more points in my Question, please check Point 1 and Point 2.. hope you can also help me with these points.

Comment: not working for me, i'm checking it on `Ubuntu 12.04 and Safari 5.0` and you have added `safari plugin` in plugins list.. Is that working for you? I opened this on Firefox and it says `safari plugin is not found`.

Comment: remove that safari plugin keep only plugins: "example", and it works for me in safari 5.1.7 and all other browsers on windows

Comment: Thanks to give your valuable time for this question and you have done a great job. Thank you very much.